# Header div won't stay on top of Chrome browser

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a #header div which has a gradient background. Inside that background, there is the logo of the website, plus the navigation menu on the bottom. That #header div is supposed to be on top of the browser - not fixed, but without any padding/margin, otherwise it would leave block of body background.

This is exactly what it's happening on Chrome. Instead of staying in the top of the browser, it is like if 30px of margin-top was put inside the #header. Funny thing is that it works perfectly on Safari, i.e., it stays on the top of the browser.

This is my code:

```
        <div id = "header">

            <div id = "header-content">

                <p id = "logo"> Components </p>

                <div id = "menu-links-div">

                    <ul id = "ul-links">
                        <a href = "index.php"> <li class = "menu-links"> Home </li> </a>
                        <a href = "media.php"> <li class = "menu-links"> Media </li> </a>
                        <a href = "sobre.php"> <li class = "menu-links"> Sobre </li> </a>
                        <a href = "contato.php"> <li class = "menu-links"> Contatos </li> </a>
                    </ul>

                </div>  

            </div>

        </div>
```

And the CSS:

```
body {
   margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-size: 100%; vertical-align: baseline; background: transparent;
   box-sizing:border-box; -moz-box-sizing:border-box; -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; height:100%; -webkit-font-smoothing:subpixel-antialiased; font-size:13px;
}

#header {
   display: inline-block;
   width: 100%;
   background: rgba(90,137,173,1);
   background: -moz-linear-gradient(left, rgba(90,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(195,223,245,1) 51%, rgba(90,137,173,1) 100%);
   background: -webkit-gradient(left top, right top, color-stop(0%, rgba(90,137,173,1)), color-stop(51%, rgba(195,223,245,1)), color-stop(100%, rgba(90,137,173,1)));
   background: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, rgba(90,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(195,223,245,1) 51%, rgba(90,137,173,1) 100%);
   background: -o-linear-gradient(left, rgba(90,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(195,223,245,1) 51%, rgba(90,137,173,1) 100%);
   background: -ms-linear-gradient(left, rgba(90,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(195,223,245,1) 51%, rgba(90,137,173,1) 100%);
   background: linear-gradient(to right, rgba(90,137,173,1) 0%, rgba(195,223,245,1) 51%, rgba(90,137,173,1) 100%);
   filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#5a89ad', endColorstr='#5a89ad', GradientType=1 );
}


#logo {
   text-align: center;
   font-size: 7.5em;
   margin-top: 105px;
   font-family: Alien;
}

#header-content {
   margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: Validate your HTML. This is not legal:

<a> <li> Sobre </li> </a>

The only thing that can surround a list item is a list element.

Comment: [Works fine](http://jsfiddle.net/xqv09mjz/). **But** take Rob's advise into account and verify your HTML. Also, why do you need your header to be displayed inline-block? Block should suffice. A problem might be padding inside html. Change 'body' in your css to `html, body`.